# Error using x86 NAnt Custom Task on 64bit machine

Tags: c#, nant

I have written a NAnt custom task in C# to clean out a set of tables in an Access database. This was all working fine for years on my 32 bit Windows machine. Now I'm on a Windows 7 64 bit box and here the troubles start.
To avoid problems accessing an Access database from a 64 bit process I've set the build target for my custom task from AnyCPU to x86 (check: [Accessing a .mdb database in 64 Bit Platform](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce9f68ae-5abf-4070-8a37-e3cc839dd13f/accessing-a-mdb-database-in-64-bit-platform?forum=netfx64bit)). But know NAnt seems to be unable to load the custom task => `Invalid element <CleanOutAccessDB>. Unknown task or datatype.` (I've double checked that the custom task dll is in the NAnt bin folder).

Any ideas how I can run a x86 custom task with NAnt on a 64 bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

Either run NAnt as a 32-bit process [`%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe`](http://www.tipandtrick.net/how-to-open-and-run-32-bit-command-prompt-in-64-bit-x64-windows/) or run an `<exec>` task into a 32-bit Access exe.